# Django and Celery: scheduled task is running, but doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: python, django, celery

I have created a Celery task in my Django app to scrape data and save it to database:

```
#tasks.py
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
import datetime
from .models import Listing, City #, ScrapingDate
from .scrapers import AIRBNB_scraper_from_jason

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')),
    name="scrape_capitals_listings",
    ignore_result=True
)
def scrape_capitals_listings():
    default_checkin = datetime.date.today()
    default_checkout = default_checkin + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    counter = 0
    capitals = City.objects.filter(status='capital')
    for capital in capitals:
        print('Scraping listings for ' + capital.name)
        capitals_scraper = AIRBNB_scraper_from_jason(city=capital.name, checkin=default_checkin, checkout=default_checkout)
        capitals_listings = capitals_scraper.scraped_data
        for capital_listing in capitals_listings:
            listing = Listing()
            listing.name = capital_listing[0]
            listing.link = capital_listing[1]
            listing.price = capital_listing[2]
            listing.city = capital
            listing.country = capital.country
            listing.continent = capital.continent
            listing.date_added = datetime.datetime.now()
            listing.save()
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            break
```

In my views.py I call the task like this:

```
from .tasks import scrape_capitals_listings

def dashboards(request):
    scrape_capitals_listings.delay()# I have also tried just "scrape_capitals_listings"
    capitals_chart = create_capitals_chart()
    context = {'capitals_chart':capitals_chart}

    return render(request, 'javascript/dashboards.html', context)
```

The I run the server, Redis broker,`celery -A test_project -l info` and `celery -A test_project beat -l info` in separate terminals.

I can see that the scheduled task is being sent by Celery like this `[2018-08-17 07:16:00,018: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task scrape_capitals_listings (scrape_capitals_listings)`, but nothing gets saved to the database.

The function code is working fine when called from within view normally, not as a Celery task, so I guess I am missing some important step here?

Comment: did you include the _settings.py_  changes required for celery? and also did you add 
`from .celery import app as celery_app`
and 
`__all__ = ['celery_app']` in the _init.py_

Comment: Yes, I did.........

Comment: could you `print(capitals_listings)` and `print(listing)` and check if the value is correct or not?

Comment: Nothing will get printed, correct nor wrong. Even if I simplify the celery task to just print statement, it won't get printed - so I suspect I am missing some connecting link between tasks.py and views.py (even though the task gets executed as in my question)

Comment: can you share a small git repo, with all the steps you are following? I have faced such issue in the past. I can help you out

Comment: can you please  add `@celery.task` just above `def scrape_capitals_listings()` after importing celery i.e `import celery` in `tasks.py` @barciewicz
you can check .. my earlier approach.. that can also be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664166/django-celery-scheduling-a-manage-py-command/51429597#51429597

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **periodic tasks** you need to start the `celerybeat` service.

```
$ celerybeat
```

or

```
$ celeryd -B
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.0-archived/getting-started/periodic-tasks.html#starting-celerybeat

Comment: You are right, but I did that, I just made a mistake in my question. It is updated now.